# get the total size of a record in a table across a column - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a column in mysql where I needed to retrieve the size of the total records in a table across a column in my symfony apps.

Here is the structure of the table where I want to get the total size of records in the agrees column so in this case it should return 2:

```
id | agrees | disjoint |
1  |  1     | 0
2  |  1     | null
```

Below is my approach but it just fetches everything from the table but I cannot count the size of the agrees column

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxxBundle:Entity')->findAll();

      $data = array();
        foreach ($restresults as $restresult) {

            array_push($data, $this->serialize($restresult));

        }

     $response = new Response(json_encode($data), 200);
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Please how can I get the total size of records in the column?

Comment: You want to count `no of records` or `sum of agrees`?

Comment: number of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need count elements in the table, use:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(e.id)');
$qb->from('xxxBundle:Entity','e');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

If you need sum column, use

```
$qb->select('sum(e.agrees)');
```

More info in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: You do not know symfony -_- entity manager is doctrine.. in controller $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();